# How to enable the php 5.4.x version on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac, php, osx-mountain-lion

I have installed the latest php version on my mountain lion system using these instructions (http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/).
I even put /usr/local/bin first in my path variable, so when I run php -v at the command line I get php v5.4.x
The problem is that when I run a simple script (with the phpinfo() function inside) the page tells me that I am running the old 5.3.x php version that comes pre-installed with mac os mountain lion.
I even tried to restart apache, but the problem remains.
Any ideas on this one?
Thank you.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could try XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html. I find it a lot easier to configure and run than OS X's Apache/PHP combo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial you followed is a bit dangerous. It seems it tells you to replace the default X11 with a new one, which is a really bad unnecessary idea.

Where did you change your local variable? If you used .profile or .bash_profile it is only valid for your user. To affect all users you need to change /etc/paths. But I don't think it has anything to do with the PATH var.

---

Regarding your question, this means Apache is not loading the correct PHP module. (libphp5.so)

Check the creation date of `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

If it predates your build time, then it was not replaced.

1. First turn off Apache (either in Settings or by running `sudo apachectl stop` in the console).
2. Then rename `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` -->`sudo mv /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so.bak`
3. Then go to the source dir and run `make install`. (if you have deleted the directory, the makefile or ran `make clean` you will need to start the compilation process again)
4. Then check if `libphp5.so` exists at `/usr/libexec/apache2/`.  If it does not exist, then your compilation parameters are wrong. If it does, go to step 5.
5. Rename the new `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` to libphp5.4.8.so (or the version you're installing).
6. Backup httpd.conf --> `sudo cp /usr/libexec/apache2/httpd.conf /usr/libexec/apache2/httpd.conf.bak`
7. Edit httpd.conf --> `sudo nano /usr/libexec/apache2/httpd.conf` and change `LoadModule php5_module   libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` to `LoadModule php5_module  libexec/apache2/libphp5.4.8.so`
8. Put the old libphp5.so back. --> `sudo mv /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so.bak /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
9. Restart apache (in settings or with `sudo apachectl start`)

Let me know if it worked for you